# How to post entity using volley library in Android?

Tags: android, android-volley, httpurlconnection

How to implement following code using volley? I need to post and receive answer from server.

```
HttpURLConnection    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) postUrl.openConnection();
urlConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
// urlConnection.setHostnameVerifier(hostnameVerifier);

urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);


//Send request
OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
out.write(data);
out.close();

//Get Response
InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
String line;
StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null)
{
    response.append(line);
    response.append('\r');
}
rd.close();

ret = response.toString();
```

Comment: Create a `Request` and override `getParams()`, or `getBody()`? There are plenty of examples out there that illustrate how to do this, so what step exactly are you having problems with? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Go through this great tutorial [Android working with Volley Library](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/) which covers both GET and POST request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override appropriate methods in Request class.

For StringRequest:

```
Response.Listener<String> listener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    //consume response
                }
};

StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, listener, errorListener) {

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> header = new HashMap<>();
            header.put("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
            header.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            ...
            return header;
        }

        @Override
        public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
            String someContent = "{\"key\"=\"\value\"}";
            return someContent.getBytes();
        }
};
```

Then add request to your request queue:

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
queue.add(request);
```

Comment: Thank you a lot.  I was not able to post string data to server. God bless you.